# Updating kubectl with new configurations

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

As I need to change Kubernetes cluster details I picked up ca.pem of master and ran following command in my local machine with correct path to my new ca.pem

```
$ kubectl config set-cluster default-cluster --  server=https://${MASTER_HOST} --certificate-authority=${CA_CERT}
$ kubectl config set-credentials default-admin --certificate-authority=${CA_CERT} --client-key=${ADMIN_KEY} --client-certificate=${ADMIN_CERT}
$ kubectl config set-context default-system --cluster=default-cluster --user=default-admin
$ kubectl config use-context default-system
```

When I try to get nodes:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

It gives an error as follows:

```
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for xxx.xx.xx.209, xxx.xx.xx.209, not xxx.xx.xx.216
```

xxx.xx.xx.209 means my old master and it still not changed to new master. What should I do to change the master and update kubectl accordingly.

Comment: What are you trying to do ?   typically above level of interaction with kubernetes internals is not necessary and better avoided

Comment: I need to change kubernetes cluster master. so I got new ca.pem from new master. How to configure that?

Comment: Why?   What problem are you trying to solve by changing master?

Comment: I got a DNS issue with previous cluster and  created a new cluster. Need to update kubectl accordingly.

Comment: I guess you have entered the ca.pem of older master which had an ip like x.x.x.209 then created a new master with ip x.x.x.219 or you have changed the ip of older master to x.x.x.219. Which one have you done?

Comment: This was an issue happen when generating pem files in the nodes. Cause by config issue. Thanks all for supporting :)

Comment: When changing the kubernetes master's IP address, you have to update the master's certificates too if they reference the master by IP address. Check the cert's info with something like `openssl x509 -in apiserver.pem -text -noout`